# A problem with irreducible closed sets

Tags: general-topology

I am having a bit of trouble understanding a claim in Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry book, although the the problem is entirely topological at the moment.

At the start of the proof of Proposition 2.6 (there's a fully faithful functor from the category of varieties over $K$ into category of schemes over $\text{Spec}K$) Hartshorne claims the following:

> Let $X$ be any(!) topological space and let $t(X) =
>  \left\{\text{nonempty irreducible closed subsets of } X\right\}$. If
>   $Y\subseteq X$ is a closed subset then $t(Y)\subseteq t(X)$.

Although this looks really simple I'm struggling to finish the proof of this by myself. Firstly - as a space in itself - the closed subsets of $Y$ correspond to preimages of closed subsets of $X$ under the inclusion map $Y\hookrightarrow X$; equivalently, they are sets of the form $B\cap Y$ where $B$ is closed in $X$.

So let's take $A\in t(Y)$ so that $A = B \cap Y$ for some closed $B\subseteq X$. Now suppose that we write $B = B_1 \cup B_2$ for some closed $B_1$ and $B_2$ in $X$. Then $A = (Y\cap B_1)\cup (Y\cap B_2)$ is an expression for $B$ as a union of closed subsets. Irreducibility of $A$ in $Y$ implies that (WLOG) $A = Y\cap B_1$, and so $Y\cap B_2 = \varnothing$. I'd like to somehow use this - along with the fact that $Y$ is closed - to show that $B = B_1$ and thus conclude it is irreducible. However, it's not obvious to me how to do this - can anyone help me?

The second problem is that even if we are able to conclude that $A = Y\cap B$ for irreducible $B$, it's not immediately clear to me why $B = A$, and why $A$ is thus an element of $t(X)$. So an explanation of this would also be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Note that $Y$ is a closed subspace of $X$, so the closed subspaces of $Y$ are also closed in $X$. With your notation, you can *choose* $B$ to be $A$.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch of course! Thanks for reminding me of this